# Difference between the img tag dimensions seen in the inspector window and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to post the dimensions of a img tag to a php  file and then I found that there is a difference the dimensions  specified by the inspector  and that returned by  the Javascript and JQuery functions.

Here i present the HTML code containig only the necessary materials and not the whole code -

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <style>
        img{
            max-width : 600px;
            max-height: 600px;
        }
     </style>
   </head>
   <body>
     <img id="photo" src="milky_way.jpg">
     <script>   
         document.write(
            "<br/>Dimensions returned by Javascript : <br/>"+
            "Width : "+document.getElementById("photo").width+
            "Height : "+document.getElementById("photo").height
            );
     </script>

   </body>
 </html>
```

Here is the screenshot of the of my result -

[image]

As you can seen that the javascript code returns width and height as -
600 and 338 respectively
while  when checking the dimensions through inspector window it is - 
720 and 405 respectively.

Moreover the image's original dimensions are - 1920 x 1080.
Why is there such difference ?

Comment: Please check zooming of browser window..... This might be the case either you have zoom-out the browser window. Please make sure the same by by pressing "ctrl + 0"

Comment: I did it and then the values shown by the inspector changed. So what does the value shown by the inspector mean ?

Comment: Inspector will show the height/width of image that is currently present on screen irrespective of actual height/width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `width`/`height` you see there are the actual values you see.

If you want to get the original width/height of an image you can create a new `img` object, and get the values from that object (onload):

```js
document.write(
  "<br/>Dimensions returned by Javascript : <br/>"+
  " Width : "+document.getElementById("photo").width+
  " Height : "+document.getElementById("photo").height
);
var img = new Image()
img.src = document.getElementById("photo").getAttribute('src')
img.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "<br/>Original Dimensions : <br/>"+
  " Width : "+this.width+
  " Height : "+this.height
}
```

```css
img{
            max-width : 600px;
            max-height: 600px;
        }
```

```html
<img id="photo" src="https://dummyimage.com/1920x1080/000/fff">
<div id="result"></div>
```

> In your screenshot - Firefox show the **actual** width/height an element is taking on the screen (and if you are in zoomin/zoomout - it will take that zoom into account). This is not the behavior in Chrome, for example. Chrome will ignore the zoom-effect.
>
> You can set default zooming (using <kbd>CTRL+0</kbd>) and check again.

Answer (score 1):

The max-height property is used to set the maximum height of an element.This prevents the value of the height property from becoming larger than max-height.
for example if you have an image with `600px` of `height` then if you set `img` `max-height:500px` the image will shrink but if you set `max-height:700px` the image height is always `600px` height and max-height is different

Comment: So how do you explain the different values (720px width in the inspector and 600px in the javascript code - `document.getElementById("photo").width`)? The inspector should tell the actual dimensions the element takes (on the screen). In the above example - it's 600px (width) and not 720px.

Comment: He is setting `max-heigth` to 600px, but in his inspector it says 720.

Comment: that is the orginal value of the image, when you set max-width:600px; the image width is shrink , also height

Comment: @Naila You should put that explanation in your answer, cause you're right. Donno why downvote

Comment: @Daenu there is a difference between inspectors. You can read more in my answer.